# Can you set code regions in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When writing c#, in Visual Studio, you can set [regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek(VS.71).aspx) to group code accordingly.  Being new to Xcode I can't seem to find a similar feature.

Comment: Don't do this, hidden code, out of sight, out of mind, is dangerous. IMHO. First thing I do in any editor is turn off code folding.

Comment: @MarkAllanson, what, like in dlls? :)
I disagree, often you want to work on a code file and ignore large parts of it. Such as working with the delegate methods of a tableview, when your data source is done and dusted, or collapsing large parts of a utility class, so you can work on the current method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using Xcode editor, you can collapse or expand any block of code by clicking in the little left margin. Moreover, you can put a mark in any point in the code with:

`#pragma mark` *your title as long as you want*

Your mark will then appear in the middle popup menu on top of the editor window.

---

Update: I have found that a duplicate of this question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288508/xcode-regions). The answers may be of interest.

Comment: That is similar, but not quite the same.  Regions have start and end points you can also collapse and expand.

Comment: the #pragma mark doesn't seem to do the same thing.  But it's better than nothing.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, since Xcode does not implement #region, I've tried to find something similar.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use:

```
// MARK: -
```

or

```
// MARK: Initialization
```

which is more portable than #pragma mark.

Comment: this one is actually cool but gets lost in comments as they both have same green colour. but albeit nice

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for being pedantic but it's "Xcode", not "X-Code".

You can for example go:

```
#pragma mark -
```

or

```
#pragma mark Initialization
```

This will give you this kind of thing:

[image]

Comment: no need to be pragmatic I need to know what's right.  Thanks and thanks for the screen shot.

Answer (score 7):

one more option

```
#pragma mark - Initialization
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a folding zone with a custom section of your code then put your desired code inside braces `{` `}`, and it will become a folding zone.

But you have to keep in mind that braces also define variables scope, so this code should not have variables declarations which will be used outside these brackets.

Comment: And is also syntactically legal only where a block is legal.  You can't, for example, group a set of function declarations with this.

Answer (score 3):

Without support for .Net style regions, being able to collapse all your functions is the next best thing.

<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>left arrow</kbd>
to collapse.

<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>right arrow</kbd>
to expand.

Xcode will remember the last state of collapsed functions.