# Folding some parts of code (variable declarations and if blocks)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there any possible way to fold some parts of my code in Xcode 4.2 ? I'm not asking for folding methods and statement blocks 'coz it's already supported in XCode.

***EDIT***: I have 100 lines of code that contain vars, math operations, if statements, switch blocks, etc. I want to fold these lines together.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364484/xcode-enable-code-folding-by-default).

Comment: im sorry, but the question you mentioned talks about the default code folding

Comment: You might want to clarify what you're talking about then.

Comment: put these 100 lines in a separate method and then just call that method from wherever you need. Might not be the best solution though ;)

Comment: these 100 lines can't be placed in a method, you might face such case many times.

Answer (score 2):

> I have 100 lines of code that contain vars, math operations, if statements, switch blocks, etc ... I want to fold these lines together.

For the `if` statements and blocks, you can follow the instructions at [How to collapse all methods in XCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2834605).

If you are using Objective C, then you can instrument your code with a `#pragma mark` and it will be collapsible. A `#pragma mark` is a lot like a Visual Studio `#region`. See [Can you set code regions in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574953) for more details.