# Is there a way to set custom collapsable code regions in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, folding

Is there a way to create custom collapsable code regions in Xcode similar to how Visual Studio can fold around #region/#endregion blocks?

It would be nice to throw all autogenerated content into a region that I can fold away until I need to look at it. #pragma mark doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See: [Xcode regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288508/xcode-regions) for a longer discussion, but the answer is, unfortunately, "not without an ugly hack."