# Hiding @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-organization

Let me start by saying I am not sure if this belongs here or at Super User. I started here.

Now, I am a very tidy person, and I like collapsing methods so that I can get around very easily. However, one thing that aggravates me is that all my `@synthesize` commands are always there. I can see no way to collapse them. (I have over 50 properties to synthesize) Is there a way I can hide these commands, while not messing up my build.

Thanks.

Comment: Switch to the latest Xcode, and remove the `@synthesize` commands altogether :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, from "available features" perspective, `XCode` is a very old IDE. Therefore no  foldable code regions - see detailed discussion [Xcode regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288508/xcode-regions)

Also note that with the latest compiler (LLVM 4.0), declaring `@synthesize` is optional. You can enable/disable it in compiler settings in your project settings.
However, if you are using GCC or an older LLVM version (for whatever reasons), this is not possible.

Edit:
After rereading your question... having 50 properties in one class smells very bad. Consider splitting your class into several smaller classes.

You can also put the `@synthesize` commands to the end of the `@implementation` file.

Comment: That's great! I didn't know that. I'll just get rid of the lines. Also, my class is quite big, but a lot of those properties is because I am obsessed with controlling the UI. I change almost every UI element. :) It's just one app and I have over 10 classes. Most are not nearly as big as this one though.

Answer (score 1):

Since Xcode 4.4 you don't need to `@synthesize` properties if you don't want another name for it — it uses [auto synthesise](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html).