# Folding variables list Xcode

Tags: xcode, plugins, ide, xcode7, folding

I'm using embedXcode for my Arduino project and was wondering if there is a way to fold a list of variables not encapsulated by a function? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so. But if it makes sense, you might be able to encapsulate them into some "model" object, achieving someone very similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is partially answered here...(although it doesn't appear there is a particularly nice way of doing it).

[Xcode regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288508/xcode-regions)